# Problem in sorting a vector using recursion

Tags: c++11, recursion, vector

i am getting the inputed vector as the output as it is.

code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void insert(vector<int> v,int val){
   if(v.size()==0 || v[v.size()-1]<=val ){
     v.push_back(val);
     return;
   }
   int x = v[v.size()-1];
   v.pop_back();
   insert(v,val);
   v.push_back(x);
   return;
}
void fun(vector<int> v){
   if( v.size()==0 )
    return;
   int val = v[ v.size()-1 ];
   v.pop_back();
   fun(v);
   insert(v,val);
   return;
}
int main() {
 vector<int> v{9,4,1,-2,10,1,12,5,0,-4};
 fun(v);
 auto x= v.begin();
 for(;x!=v.end();x++)
    cout<<*x<<" ";
  }
```

the out put is the same input vector ,i.e
O/p : 9,4,1,-2,10,1,12,5,0,-4
please tell where am i going wrong

Comment: In order for us to know why it is going *wrong* we first must know what *right* is. You never told us what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: All your functions are pass-by-value meaning a copy of the vector is used.

Comment: You need to use a reference parameter: `void fun(vector<int> &v)`

Comment: `void insert(vector<int> &v,int val)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing vector using a reference that's why the changes are not showing.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void insert(vector<int> &v,int val){ // Passing vector by reference
   if(v.size()==0 || v[v.size()-1]<=val ){
     v.push_back(val);
     return;
   }
   int x = v[v.size()-1];
   v.pop_back();
   insert(v,val);
   v.push_back(x);
   return;
}
void fun(vector<int> &v){ // Passing vector by reference
   if( v.size()==0 )
    return;
   int val = v[ v.size()-1 ];
   v.pop_back();
   fun(v);
   insert(v,val);
   return;
}
int main() {
 vector<int> v{9,4,1,-2,10,1,12,5,0,-4};
 fun(v);
 auto x= v.begin();
 for(;x!=v.end();x++)
    cout<<*x<<" ";
  }
```